# Spring-Security : SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, session-state

I am working on a Spring-MVC application which uses Spring-Security for authentication and related security purpose. Currently I am having problem querying the sessionRegistry to get a list of currently online users as the getAllPrincipals() method always contains NULL. I tried solutions mentioned in the documentation and many suggestions mentioned on other SO threads. I would really appreciate some help as I am trying various combinations which will work to get list of all Online users.

Here is my security-application-context.xml:

```
     <import resource="servlet-context.xml" />

    <!-- Global Security settings -->
    <security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
    <security:http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>

    <security:http create-session="ifRequired" use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" disable-url-rewriting="true">
        <security:form-login login-page="/login" login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" default-target-url="/canvas/list" always-use-default-target="false" authentication-failure-url="/denied.jsp" />
        <security:remember-me key="_spring_security_remember_me" user-service-ref="userDetailsService" token-validity-seconds="1209600" data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
        <security:logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"/>
    <security:port-mappings>
        <security:port-mapping http="80" https="443"/>
    </security:port-mappings>
    <security:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/" success-handler-ref="myLogoutHandler"/>
    </security:http>
        <bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />
        <beans:bean id="sas" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy">
            <beans:constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
            <beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="-1" />
        </beans:bean>
  <beans:bean id="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices">
        <beans:property name="key" value="_spring_security_remember_me" />
        <property name="alwaysRemember" value="true"/>
        <beans:property name="tokenRepository" ref="jdbcTokenRepository"/>
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="LoginServiceImpl"/>
    </beans:bean>
 <beans:bean id="myAuthFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="sas"/>
        <property name="rememberMeServices" ref="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider"/>
        <property name="allowSessionCreation" value="true"/>
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    </beans:bean>
    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="LoginServiceImpl">
           <security:password-encoder  ref="encoder"/>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
    <beans:bean id="encoder"             class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="11" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
                class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
                <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="LoginServiceImpl"/>
               <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="encoder"/>
    </beans:bean>
```

here is where I am trying to get back the list of OnlineUsers :

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class OnlineUsersServiceImpl implements OnlineUsersService {

  @Autowired
    @Qualifier("sessionRegistry")
    private SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;

 @Override
    public boolean checkIfUserhasSession(int id) {

        Person person = this.personService.getPersonById(id);
        String email = person.getUsername();
        List<Object> principals = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals();
        for (Object principal : principals) {
            // It never reaches here
            System.out.println("We reached here");
            if (principal instanceof User) {
                  String username = ((User) principal).getUsername();
                System.out.println("Username is "+username);
                    if(email.equals(username)){
                        return true;
                    }

            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Any help would be nice. As I am on this hopeless thing since 3-4 days.

Answer (score 0):

Before injecting session registry you need to define session management part in your  security-application-context.xml

In concurrency-control section you should set alias for session registry object

```
<security:http access-denied-page="/error403.jsp" use-expressions="true" auto-config="false">
        <security:session-management session-fixation-protection="migrateSession" session-authentication-error-url="/login.jsp?authFailed=true"> 
            <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" expired-url="/login.html" session-registry-alias="sessionRegistry"/>
        </security:session-management>

    ...
    </security:http>
```

> For java based configuration alternative to xml configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // ...
        http.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1).sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher> httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher>(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it ok if I use 5 sessions by default, as we want to have multiple sessions across multiple devices. Also, I don't have the file you mentioned above, I presume it will not effect any other functionality.

Comment: Btw, you have given me ServletListenerRegistrationBean from Spring-Boot, I am not using spring-boot. I am using Spring-MVC. I am getting an Error ServletListenerRegistrationBean, cannot resolve symbol. And because of that the protected void configure method does not oveeride method from its superClass.

Comment: The pastebin for WebMVCConfigurerAdapter.java, has no method called configre. Pastebin link : http://pastebin.com/2PdU5nFA

Comment: Java section and  xml are alternative to each other I have edited the file name.

Comment: Tried your new code, sorry, it didn't change anything. Do you want me to put up some other files so you can understand what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

You need additional configuration in web.xml - listener for login/logout events

```
<listener>
   <listener-class>
    org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
   </listener-class>
</listener>
```